# pyplot modify the title color of the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

While I have found the way to change the Main Title of the subplots:

```
fig.suptitle(self.title,color='#555555', fontsize = self.parameters['labelsize'][0])
```

I didn't found a way in order to change the default black color of the title of each subplot.

Comment: Does "everywhere" include [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_demo.html)? Or maybe you want to go more in detail about what exact problem you face.

Answer (score 0):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest [specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543810/pyplot-modify-the-title-color-of-the-subplots#comment90055591_51543810), you can modify the colors of the title of the plots with the `color` argument of the `ax.set_title` method.

Check the [matplotlib color demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_demo.html) for the source.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, 201)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

# 1) RGB tuple:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor=(.18, .31, .31))
# 2) hex string:
ax.set_facecolor('#eafff5')
# 3) gray level string:
ax.set_title('Voltage vs. time chart', color='0.7')
# 4) single letter color string
ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]', color='c')
# 5) a named color:
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage [mV]', color='peachpuff')
# 6) a named xkcd color:
ax.plot(t, s, 'xkcd:crimson')
# 7) Cn notation:
ax.plot(t, .7*s, color='C4', linestyle='--')
# 8) tab notation:
ax.tick_params(labelcolor='tab:orange')


plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with changed colors in labels and titles]